In .NET 9, serialization of style using XamlWriter and XamlReader throws exception
In .NET 9, serialization and deserialization of style using XamlWriter and XamlReader throws exception. But in .NET 8 and other framework versions, it works fine. Please find the code below.
In .NET 9, most of the setter tags do not have <Setter.Value> tags in the output file which results in the exception.
public string filePath = "style.xml";

StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();

// for saving
Style style = new Style(typeof(System.Windows.Shapes.Path));
style.Setters.Add(new Setter(System.Windows.Shapes.Path.StretchProperty, Stretch.Fill));
style.Setters.Add(new Setter(System.Windows.Shapes.Path.FillProperty, Brushes.Black));            

System.Windows.Markup.XamlWriter.Save(style, stringWriter);

File.WriteAllText(filePath, stringWriter.ToString());

// for loading

string xamlContent = File.ReadAllText(filePath);

// Parse the XAML content back into a Style object
using (StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(xamlContent))
{
    using (XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(stringReader))
    {
        Style loadedStyle = (Style)XamlReader.Load(xmlReader);                    
    }
}

How can we overcome this issue in .NET 9?

what exception ?

I've just tested ... exception is irrelevant here, as it is thrown by XamlReader.Load ... and yes, FillProperty missing the Setter.Value  element (and that's why load throws) ... seems like bug in dotnet 9 ... please report it on github
